# MacBook Pro 13 mid 2009 wifi hardware not detected- peculiar case

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, wifi, bluetooth

The question is as the title says. I just installed my optical drive back into it's place, and a few cables got loose (namely the audio and "display" cables). I plugged them back in and switched on the Mac, but it said wifi hardware not detected. Normally one would assume it's a problem with the display cable (which is the cable for Bluetooth, the camera and wifi), but Bluetooth is working perfectly, the camera is functioning, but the wifi icon on the task bar still says the same thing. I ran a system report and refreshed it, and surprisingly the wifi card was being detected there! I reset PRAM and the SMC to no avail. What's going on?

Comment: Try re-seating (removing and reinstalling) the Airport (wireless) card.  Also run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.  It's possible that the network portion of the card may just have gone sideways and it now needs to be replaced.

Comment: @Allan I can't boot into AHT for some reason. Also, I'm not very comfortable in going to the airport card, because it is buried quite deep inside the Mac. Are you sure the issue lies there? Because it seems to be something in the optical Bay Area only.

Comment: Re-seat means connect/reconnect.  Disconnect and reconnect whatever it is you serviced previously.  Did you try Option-D?  Also, you may need Disk 2 if you MBP came with installation disks.

Comment: @Allan what I had exactly done is this: A few months ago I had an SSD installed with a optical drive caddy. So both the original HDD and the new SSD were in the Mac. The HDD eventually stopped working, so today placed SSD where the HDD was and removed the HDD completely (I also removed the optical drive caddy). This was to lower the weight of the Mac. When I switched it on after this everything was fine. Now I had the optical drive of the mac lying around, so I decided now that I'm here, I might as well put that in. So I put it in and to insert the screw I disconnected the "display" cable...

Comment: ...and plugged it back in. Everything seemed fine. Then when I switched the mac on, everything above happened. Please give me advice as to how to go about this.

Comment: Only 2 cables from the display - LVDS (display) and camera data cable (near the optical bay).  If you disconnected that cable, you need to remove it and plug it back in - make sure it's in securely.  Next, you need to either run AHT, boot in Safe, or Recovery mode.  If WiFi doesn't work in any of those, then you most likely have a hardware issue with the Airport card

Comment: Just in case you need any sort of 2nd opinion, I agree 100% with @Allan - your next steps are to disconnect/reconnect the cables (and while you're at it, make sure nothing else has worked its way loose) and then retest your Wi-Fi. If no go, boot into Safe Mode and test again. Also run AHT. If the 2nd installation disk as suggested by Allan doesn't work, then let me know and I'll prove instructions on creating a bootable AHT USB flash drive for you.

Comment: @Monomeeth.. this is looking pretty bad now. Suddenly a folder with a question mark appears on screen and I can't boot into osx anymore. I can't even go into recovery or safe mode.

Comment: Just so I can get a full picture of your situation... Do you have a Time Machine (or other) backup of your data? Also, when you say the HDD eventually stopped working, did you confirm that was the case via any testing? And, if I understand your history, everything was fine until you decided to re-add the optical drive, is that right? Finally, in terms of trying to boot into recovery mode, did you try all possible key combinations during startup (i.e. ⌘+R, Option, Option+⌘+R) to see what happens?

Comment: @Monomeeth I have no backup of my data. I have ordered an HDD enclosure for this purpose, because I'm pretty confident the SSD itself is okay. I think the problem is that there is no existing recovery disk partition on my SSD, because the Mac seems to understand what command I am giving it, but can't seem to find the actual interface it needs to display to me. I believe the last person whom I had trusted to install macOS only installed the OS, and no other partitions. I have some understanding of the reason for the wifi not working, but the reason for the SSD going kaput is still unknown.

Comment: @Monomeeth What I am planning to do is backing up my data via the aforementioned HDD enclosure, and then take the Mac to a service center nearby. I believe they should have a copy of macOS El Capitan. Then I would want them to format the disk and reinstall macOS. If all is well, then I'll leave. But if the wifi problem persists, I will have them take a look at the wire connections, to see if any are broken or not firmly connected. It's a little annoying because I need to go to the service center. If you have any DIY solution, or another method it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I must be missing something - how are you going to back up your data with a HDD enclosure? Have you got a HDD you're going to put in it? Or, if you're planning to put your SSD in it, well, that's not a backup of your data, that's just moving your data. As for why your _SSD is going kaput_, if that's the case these things can happen to any drive at any time, hence why backups are critical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57947/discussion-between-monomeeth-and-mythic-cocoa).

Comment: I fixed the hard drive and backed up all the data. But the wifi problem persists. Please help me out.